# Sql server - find ranges of a column based on another

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to validate some data, I want to find the min and max of column B for select values of column A. It looks like this:

```
Select min(colB), max(colB)
From table 
where colA = SomeValue
```

What I'm wondering is how can I specify a certain interval, say 10, that will give me every min and max of column b by every 10 A. It would function like this:

```
 for(int i = minValueOfColA; 1<maxValueOfColA;i+=10){   
    Select min(colB), max(colB)
    From table 
    where colA = i
}
```

Except I'd like to do it in sql.

Comment: Can you please add some test data and your desired output from that data?

Comment: Sql server doesn't support for loop. Use a while loop to simulate for loop and everything should be fine

Comment: Declare counter
SET counter = minValueOfColA
while (counter<maxValueofColA)
begin
counter = counter+10
--rest of code
end

Comment: @RamGrandhi - I think the point was to show a pseudo code except only that OP wants to implement the same logic in SQL

Comment: @GurV Yes, what I have given was only a pseudo code. That's why not posted it as a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you think this could solve your problem (without CTE)?:

```
CREATE TABLE T2 (COLA INT, COLB INT)
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (2,3)
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (2,5)
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (3,10)
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (4,20)
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (5,30)
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (12,35)
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (12,52)
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (13,40)


SELECT COLA, MIN(T2.COLB) AS MIN_COLB, MAX(T2.COLB) AS MAX_COLB, 
FROM T2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MIN(COLA) AS MIN_COLA FROM t2) B
GROUP BY COLA 
HAVING (COLA-MIN(B.MIN_COLA))%10=0
```

Output:

```
COLA        MIN_COLB    MAX_COLB
----------- ----------- -----------
2           3           5
12          35          52
```

Comment: This answer is much more straightforward than what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you are looking for. As the increments are `+10`, the `ColA` with value `2` will be ignored.

Query:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
colA INT,
colB INT
)

INSERT @Table VALUES(1, 2), (1, 39), (2, 2), (11, 21), (11, 42)

;WITH cteIncrement
AS
(
    SELECT MIN(colA) minColA, MAX(colA) maxColA
    FROM @Table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT minColA + 10, maxColA
    FROM cteIncrement
    WHERE minColA + 10 <= maxColA
)
SELECT MIN(t.colB) minColB, MAX(t.colB) maxColB
FROM cteIncrement cte
JOIN @Table t
ON t.colA = cte.minColA
GROUP by t.colA
```

Results:

```
+------+---------+---------+
| colA | minColB | maxColB |
+------+---------+---------+
|    1 |       2 |      39 |
|   11 |      21 |      42 |
+------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure I understand you fully, but how about something like this:

```
select a/10, min(b), max(b)
from Table
group by (a / 10)
```

You can then change the occurences of `10` to suite your choice of interval.

For prettier output of the ranges, and input of interval, something like this:

```
declare @interval int;

set @interval = 10;

select cast(a/@interval * @interval as varchar) + '-' + cast((a/@interval * @interval) + (@interval - 1) as varchar), min(b), max(b)
from Table
group by (a / @interval)
```

For a table populated like this:

```
insert into Table values (1, 1), (1, 15), (11, 3), (12, 4), (17, 8), (20, 5)
```

Gives the following result for interval=10:

```
0-9     1   15
10-19   3   8
20-29   5   5
```

And this for interval=15:

```
0-14    1   15
15-29   5   8
```

Comment: I believe the value range shall start from 1. It should be like `1-10`, `11-20` etc. from my point of view.

Comment: I would say that depends on whether or not `0` is a possible value. With the range starting from `1`, then 0-values will be ignored..

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple group by query to me:

```
SELECT MIN(ColB), MAX(ColB), ColA
FROM Table
WHERE ColA IN(<Values list>)
GROUP BY ColA
```

Now all you have to do is set that values list with values based on your interval.